# Install propel_generator 1.2?

Tags: php, installation, pear, propel

I'm trying to install propel_generator version 1.2 (later versions are incompatible with the project I'm working on). I've tried

```
pear install propel/propel_generator-1.2
```

But I get the following error:

```
Failed to download propel/propel_generator, version "1.2", 
latest release is version 1.5.2, stability "stable", 
use "channel://pear.propelorm.org/propel_generator-1.5.2" to install

install failed
```

Anybody know how I can install this using Pear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: You can't.

The explanation is:
I took a look at http://pear.propelorm.org/Chiara_PEAR_Server_REST/r/propel_generator/allreleases.xml and the earliest version of propel_generator that is available for install via PEAR from there is version 1.3.0

You could download the v1.2.0 code from http://svn.propelorm.org/tags/1.2.0/ and create a pear package.xml yourself, using their BuildPropelPEARPackageTask.php script, if you really need to.