# Need to install propel_generator version 1.3.5

Tags: php, installation, generator, pear, propel

I need to install propel_generator version 1.3.5 on my machine. I tried to install it using PEAR via:

```
pear install propel/propel_generator-1.3.5
```

but it failed with the following message:

```
Failed to download propel/propel_generator, version "1.3.5", latest release is version 1.6.7, stability "stable", use "channel://pear.propelorm.org/propel_generator-1.6.7" to install
install failed
```

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3116233/636342) I checked http://pear.propelorm.org/Chiara_PEAR_Server_REST/r/propel_generator/allreleases.xml and the earliest version of propel_generator that is available for install via PEAR from there is version **1.3.0** and the next to follow is **1.4.0** with no **1.3.5** in between.

Is there a way to install propel_generator version **1.3.5** using PEAR or any other way?

I can't even find the source code for the 1.3.5 generator.

PS: The generator is being used by a legacy system so upgrading isn't really an option.

Comment: If it's not there I'm not sure you going to find it on an "official" channel. You may want to post a message in the [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/propel-users) and see if anyone has it and can post it for you to download.

Comment: But why do you want so much the **1.3.5** version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was never an official release of 1.3.5, see the list of tags at http://svn.propelorm.org/tags/ - you won't get that version from anywhere.