# I need Propel 1.3.0. From where I can download the same?

Tags: propel

I need Propel 1.3.0 for my existing php and mysql versions to create model classes. From where I can download Propel generator 1.3.0? 
Your help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: A simple google search would have helped you, the first result is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730327/need-to-install-propel-generator-version-1-3-5 which mentiones a google group and svn repo

Comment: @Dymen1 Version 1.3.0 is not available there

Comment: As mentioned here: http://propelorm.org/download.html#full-propel-package . they moved to another URL which seems to be down at the moment, you should contact them about it.

Comment: @Dymen1 Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The oldest I could find was 1.7.1
https://github.com/propelorm/Propel

I have a copy of 1.6.7 but that's the oldest I have

Up to 1.7.1 does have a lot of backward compatibility, it was only when they went to Propel 2 that things really started to break.  There were changes at 1.5, but they were relatively minor.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I'll try with 1.7.1